# When should you use $limit in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Well, this a technical performance question:

I have a query like this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match:{...}},
    {$group:{...}},
    {$group:{...}},
    {$project:{...}},
    {$sort:...}
])
```

But if i want set limit I use `$limit` in the end on query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match:{...}},
    {$group:{...}},
    {$group:{...}},
    {$project:{...}},
    {$sort:...},
    {$limit : 10}
])
```

So my question is about whats is the best way to put $limit:

- At the beginning of the consultation.
- At the end of the consultation.
- In any part of the consultation: the order is not important.

My logic/mind says `You should to use "$limit" after $match to limit first results because maybe Mongo execute first $match and after will get result to process the next query's($group, $group, $project, $sort, ...)`.

Thanks

P.S: I am new to using Mongo. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: It's a "pipeline", therefore where you apply `$limit` is up to what your needs are. Think "Unix Pipe `|`": `sed | grep | awk | grep | sed` and so on. It depends on "where you **need** it".

Comment: Then it's as I thought: it depends where I want to affect the limit, giving priority to the order of sentences.
If I want 10 results, it is best to use it after $match because $group only would group/edit the original result of the consultation. Then, you could reuse $limit if necessary in $group.
Clearly it is an issue where the order is important.

Comment: You need to really understand the "pipeline" principle first. Order of execution into the other. No going back, no modifiying. What goes in comes out and usually altered. That's the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So why is `$limit` last in  the pipeline you propose?:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$match":{...}},
    {"$group":{...}},
    {"$group":{...}},
    {"$project":{...}},
    {"$sort":...},
    {"$limit": 10}
])
```

Because that's **exactly** what it is supposed to to.

So at the "end" of the "pipeline" is where the "last 10 results" are only returned.

This is not like a cursor modifier, the operation  happens "sequentially" so the "limit" occurs right after the stage it was implemented in.

Therefore:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
   { "$limit": 10 },
   { .. whatever .. }
])
```

Is basically controlled by only looking at the very "first" 10 documents in the collection as retrived without any other conditons, no matter what the pipeline says in the remaining stages.

A Pipeline is a "pipeline". Think "Unix Pipe `|`":

```js
grep | sed | awk | sed | grep | awk
```

Because that is **exactly** what it does. What you "feed" in is what you get "out" by the operations performed.

So every pipeline stage is important to the order in which it is performed. The place serves a purpose and is not interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

When using `$limit`, it really depends on the details. However, it is best to use `$limit` as soon as you're able to, but the order usually matters. In the unlikely case that you only need 10 random documents, then you can use `$limit` right after `$match`. However, in your case, you are also using `$sort`, which will impact what 10 objects you want to get returned; thus, you should include `$limit` after `$sort` unless your aggregate query can be optimized in a way that you could use sort and limit earlier.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { ... } },
  // Will limit results exactly as they come, unsorted
  { $limit: 10 },
  { $group: {...}},
  { $group: {...}},
  { $project: {...}},
  { $sort: ...} // Will only sort the random 10
]);

db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { ... } },
  { $group: {...}},
  { $group: {...}},
  { $project: {...}},
  { $sort: ...}, // The sort likely matters, so limit after
  { $limit: 10 }
]);
```

However, a case where it could be moved around is where you do are sort early, and you're just massaging data, which could be more performant with less data to massage:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { ... } },
  { $group: {...}},
  { $group: {...}},
  { $sort: ...},
  { $limit: 10 },
  { $project: {...}} // Since we only change the data format, it won't affect our limit
]);
```

Comment: My understanding of the question is that they're wondering when in the aggregation pipeline you should use `$limit`. Am I missing something? i.e. Right away, at the end, or it doesn't matter.

Comment: Of Course it matters. If you understood that you wouldn't have posted this "answer". `$limit` is a "pipeline" stage and is very different from "cursor" `.limit()` which I think you are confusing in this case ( as well as `$sort` and `.sort()`. Aggregation pipelines are "sequential".

Comment: @BlakesSeven: I think you misunderstood this answer. To me, he's saying the same thing as you do.

Comment: Obviously it matters. My mentioning of "it doesn't matter" was paraphrasing his question. I write aggregate queries almost daily, so I fully understand the implications. There's either some language in my answer that is not totally clear, or you're misunderstanding my answer or the question.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev If I misunderstood it ( as someone who knows the framework well ) then how are new people to take it? A poor explanation is a poor explanation.

Comment: @BlakesSeven: well, the only way to see is to take some new people and subject them to this answer. :)

Comment: @BlakesSeven A more productive comment would be related to improving the answer and addressing things specifically rather than saying that I know nothing and that you know everything when you clearly don't understand what I'm saying.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Sure let them look. But I would not hand this out as teaching material and I doubt you would either. So I don't think your voting here is really "honest" in how you would like people to learn. This cannot all be "rainbows and unicorns" with "medal of merit" badges for all. If you want a Q&A base for people to learn from then you need good examples, not unclear statements.

Comment: @BlakesSeven: you have a point. After some rephrasing, this question will look like a reference question and, as such, deserves a good answer. But Arsenal here, he's right too. Criticizing without suggesting improvements is hardly constructive.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Rembemer "unicorns and rainbows" don't assume you can spin gold out of corn. Therefore just provide an "answer that helps" rather than coax something far from the desired result into being something it is not. This is not meant to be offensive, it's just a fact.

Comment: @EmptyArsenal: in your second snippet, you forgot to remove the first `$limit`

Comment: The design of SO is to bubble up the best answers, and let the rest sink. Comments are meant to be constructive, and if there's is nothing constructive to say, cast your vote and try to write a better answer. Thanks @SergioTulentsev

Comment: Although I prefer BlakesSeven's anwer, this one is totally acceptable in my view.